# Google Classrooms Principal Account

Tags: google-classroom

When I login to google classrooms as a SuperAdmin, I can view all classrooms and also assign teachers. I need to delegate these responsibilities, so is there a way I can provision a "school principal" account, that can create classrooms and assist teachers in any classroom activity (be a co-teacher)? My hesitation with sharing the Super Admin account is that the user would full control over the domain.

Is there anything that can be done in the role privileges to customize this experience?

Comment: So you basically want to grant permission to someone to add teachers and manage all classrooms which does not have admin control over the whole domain right?

Comment: yes the account needs to be able to add new teacher and assign them to classrooms. If the account can automatically co-teach too, that would be great too!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to grant a super admin role to a user to manage classroom as an admin. Instead, you can grant a restricted admin role to one of your users either by using a pre-built admin role or by creating a [custom admin role](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043?hl=en) with the permissions you would like to grant the user. Therefore, you could grant a restricted admin role to your principal so that he can manage Google Classroom and other limited features of your domain. I tested this using `Help Desk Admin` and `Services Admin` roles.

[This](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251) is a list of the admin permissions that exist. [Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33325?hl=en) you can find more information about setting up administrator roles to other users.

However, it seems from the Original Poster reply and from my own testing that this new Classroom admin cannot modify or add teachers to other classrooms **unless he is invited to the other admin's class**. So you should invite your new admin to all your classes as a teacher and then he will be able to edit and add teachers to this class.

Comment: This isnt working. Ive assigned Help Desk Admin and Services Admin roles to a user and dont see all classes

Comment: google support just confirmed that it can't be done

Comment: Hi ! What could you do when you set ```Services Admin``` role to a user? Could this user create new classes? Could he assign new teachers? I think I know what you mean now. When I set this to one of my users the user could do all the G Suite admin functions set for classroom. However, he could **not manage** classrooms created by other admins. Was this your original intention?